# where/how to find/extract official android os (open source) translation/localization/glossary

Tags: localization, android-sdk, open-source, translate

Since the open source android (https://source.android.com) is available in multiple languages, can I extract all the translated strings in the OS so I can use them as a reference for my own app's translation? (for example for error messages...)

Or is this list available somewhere?

Probably harder to get, but I'd also like to ask the same question for the official non-open source version...

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, that's rather a development question (and thus off-topic here) – unless you can point out how that might be relevant to end-users :)

Comment: Thanks izzy :) Well, maybe you're right, but I'm not a developer, I'm just a translator and I just want to find the translation files so I can make my translations consistent to the official translations.. Should/can I move the question or should I post again somewhere else?

Comment: Hm, not sure. Your explanation can count qualifying this as "power-user question". Localization help is something every user could do. As despite of my comment nobody flagged it off-topic yet, I'd say it can stay here – though changes for good answers would be higher at SO (where the devs sit). BTW, talking "strings": you know there are `strings.xml` files in use for things like that, even with AOSP source? Related: [Android sync strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4926004/2533433) // [Android strings.xml Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7330021/2533433)